# Why didn't Gwyneth Palthrow (Pepper Potts) appear in Age of Ultron, even as a cameo?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, avengers-age-of-ultron

Why didn't Gwyneth Paltrow appear in the movie?  The off-hand explanation (She's off running the company) seemed pretty weak.   Even just a five second video conversation on-screen would have been more convincing.   So I wouldn't buy "scheduling".   Therefore, I'm assuming either Palthrow was not interested, or they couldn't come to terms.   Is there an out-of-universe information on this absence?
The status of Iron Man 4 looks pretty doubtful, but if there's any information on Paltrow's appearance in **any** future MCU film, that would be a welcome part of the answer too.

Comment: Because they'd have to pay her for no good reason on a movie that already had like 15 major stars in it?

Comment: Just pretend cap was pepper. Tony sure did

Comment: Seriously, [Marvel had trouble making a deal with Tom Hiddleston](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/JoshWildingNewsAndReviews/news/?a=120107) for a quick scene/cameo too.

Comment: Don't think you're going to get a non-opinion based answer on this.

Comment: Downvotes?   Seriously?   MCU has shown heavy use of cameos.   I don't know what the going rate is, but surely it's not that much for a couple hours of work.   And I disagree with the contention "no good reason".

Comment: there would be even less of a good reason to have Pepper in this movie than there was to have Dr. Selvig or Falcon in it. The only reason they even bothered to put her in *Avengers* was to basically tell Tony "go be an Avenger" and then vanish.

Comment: @Clyde:   Why?   There certainly could be non-opinion answers.   Sometimes there's commentary out there about not being able to reach a deal.  Or "scheduling conflicts".  Or "such-and-such" is signed up for the next film.   Etc.

Comment: @Clyde there might be an objective answer, which is why there aren't any close votes, but you're right that there probably isn't (which I suspect is why there are downvotes)

Comment: I'd guess they didn't have her on for the need for all the time they could get, since there are several big characters.

Comment: Why the downvotes?   There are two perfectly sound answers.

Comment: I downvoted because anyone with a basic knowledge of how Hollywood works should be able to figure this one out. A big name star like Gwyneth Paltrow would typically cost a studio millions of dollars even for a few minutes of screen-time. There's simply no reason to include the character, especially not at that kind of cost.

Comment: The **real** question is, will we be seeing more of Jon Favreau as Happy Hogan?

Comment: @Omegacron, I suggest you read [this](http://www.eonline.com/news/58119/do-celebs-get-paid-to-be-special-guest-stars-on-tv) and [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070608212613AAMd7RK) and [this](https://www.quora.com/Acting/How-much-do-actors-get-paid-for-cameo-appearances-in-movies)  (links of varying quality) before you assert that it necessarily costs 'millions of dollars' for a thirty second shot of Paltrow.

Comment: While it's reported that she did her spot in Avengers without counting against her contract, there is *no way* that the person who came up with [this holiday gift guide](http://goop.com/gift-guide-2014/) is doing *anything* for free.

Comment: @phantom42:   Maybe, but $10-200k wouldn't exactly have any effect on the [$280M-budget](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=age%20of%20ultron%20budget)

Comment: Maybe $10-200k is pocket change to you and Paltrow, but that's more than most of the crew makes combined. If the role isn't needed, or a budget has to be cut, stuff like that is going to be the first thing removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First, there's the issue of her contract.**

There's also the issue that according to Paltrow, [her contract with Marvel ended with Iron Man 3.](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/JoshWildingNewsAndReviews/news/?a=78107)

> While it was widely assumed that Gwyneth Paltrow was another star who had been signed up for a ridiculous number of Marvel movies, **she has now told Empire Online that her contract expired with Iron Man 3! "My deal is over as well,"** she revealed when asked whether she think Robert Downey Jr. will make a return as the armoured Avenger. "When they signed us, they signed us for three. So that's it for the moment, but you never know." However, wasn't The Avengers her third appearance as Pepper Potts?! It turns out that she actually did that as a favour (although it would obviously be more than a little naive to assume she wasn't paid for the privilege).

But as CBM mentions, she made a fourth appearance despite not being contractually obligated, so it's conceivable that she could/might have made another quick appearance if she were asked. But...

**Early indications were that Paltrow just wasn't asked.**

It sounds like Joss just didn't have a reason for her to appear.

The interview is pretty old, but [Paltrow said she just never got asked](http://screencrush.com/the-avengers-2-age-of-ultron-will-likely-leave-out-gwyneth-paltrow/).

> I don't think so, **nobody has asked me**- What is it called? 'Age of Ultron,' okay. Well, no, I don't think so. I haven't heard any...my phone has not rung for 'Avengers 2.'

**However, the movie's commentary makes it sound as though there were scheduling conflicts.**

During the scene where Thor and Tony discuss the absence of Jane and Pepper, he explains:

> There are many versions of this scene, some of them including the actresses. One of the great things about working with this many stars is that you never know who you're going to get - what schedule is going to work out, who is going to come available, or who... and so **when it became apparent that neither was going to show up,** I thought it was important to plant a flag on that and say, you know it was something that registers with our guys, and the best way to do that was to have them be dicks about it.

Comment: What is it called.....no way she didn't know t he name. haha some people.

Comment: @Clyde it's entirely possible that she didn't know the name of a movie that she wasn't involved in *two years* before it was released

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, there was never any intention for her, or her character, to appear in *Age of Ultron*. The movie is already jam packed with character and not enough time to show them all, but at least every "cameo" (War Machine, Falcon, etc.) has some minor impact on the story. It's hard to see how Pepper Potts would have affected the story at all.

As far as her future, she hasn't given any indication that she's scheduled to be in any more movies, though there are (as always) rumors that she might be in *Captain America 3*. This idea is based on the fact that Marvel can't use many of the characters who appeared in *Civil War* in the comics, so there's room to bring back existing MCU characters to replace them.

For her part, Paltrow appears more than willing to [reprise her role](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Pepper-Potts-Captain-America-3-Here-What-Gwyneth-Paltrow-Had-Say-68410.html):

> My fingers are crossed. I would love to be Pepper Potts again at some point in my life.

although she [has expressed concern](http://comicbook.com/2015/01/02/gwyneth-paltrow-thinks-she-could-be-replaced-in-iron-man-franchi/) that she's getting to old to reliably play Tony's love interest:

> “I’d like to do it,” Paltrow recently told Harper’s Bazaar. “But they might swap me out for an 18-year-old Pepper Potts or something.”

Unfortunately, there doesn't look like there are going to be any more *Iron Man* direct sequels, so the odds of seeing a new Rescue suit, for example, are pretty slim.

Comment: I would see how the OLD Tony Stark might go for an 18-year-old alternate Pepper Potts, but c'mon... this is the new & improved Tony Stark we're talking about. LOL

Comment: As it turns out, we did see Rescue after all.